# Python 2d array loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

It might be stupid question but I'm starting with python and I have no clue how to write it.

So I want to print this table in loop like on the screen and then I want it to be usable but It's hard for me to write it down (look on screen pls):

```
table = [print([random.randint(0,1) for x in range(10)]) for y in range(10)]
a = table
print(a)
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL1EK.png)

Answer (score 1):

The values are printed using the `print` inside the list. But the method `print` return nothing, `None`, so you're saving 10 `None` in the outer list

```
table = [[random.randint(0, 1) for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
for row in table:
    print(row)
a = table
print(a)
```

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for help rly appreciate.

Comment: @Neexu you can think about accepting the answer so (green tick on left) ;)